# Output the minimum after the loop

Tags: r

Here is my code:

```
for(i in 1:10000){
  table1<-table(toydata$A,toydata$B)
  toy <- toydata    # Work with a copy
  toy[] <- lapply(toydata, swapFun)
  table2<-table(toy$A,toy$B)
  print (c(i,sum(abs(table1-table2))))
  if((sum(abs(table1-table2)))<10) 
  {break}

}
```

If after 10000 times loops,  `sum(abs(table1-table2))` is still `>10`. I want the function output the minimum of `sum(abs(table1-table2))`.

How can I solve it? Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide your `toydata` either by giving us the code to create it or by using `dput()`?  Also, it would be helpful to get a description of what you want this code to do, as I suspect there's a better way to accomplish `table1 - table2`.

Comment: When you say "function output" do you mean the result of your `for` loop? If so, just end your loop with `if(i==1000 && sum(abs())>10) min(sub(abs()))`.

Comment: Hi, I mean the  minimum result of the `sum(abs(table1-table2))` after the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

I have fix it.

```
mini<-10000
for(i in 1:1000){
  table1<-table(toydata$A,toydata$B)
  toy <- toydata    # Work with a copy
  toy[] <- lapply(toydata, swapFun)
  table2<-table(toy$A,toy$B)
  print (c(i,sum(abs(table1-table2))))
  if((sum(abs(table1-table2)))<10) 
  {break}
  mini<-min(mini,sum(abs(table1-table2)))


}
print(mini)
```